# Embed Guvnor's BRL Guided Editor in web page

Tags: jboss, drools, drools-guvnor

I've created a web page that's meant to display all the BRL's in my Guvnor repository so business people can view/edit it as they please. I've checked the Guvnor documentation on Chapter 10, where they talk about this, and from what I understand this is the link that would give me access to what I want:

```
http://<address : port>/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/StandaloneEditor.html?assetsUUIDs=<myUUID>&client=oryx
```

The problem is this doesn't display anything. I've read and re-read the documentation, I've searched all over google but can't really find a tutorial or a complete example on how to do this, even with the plugtree website one.

Can anyone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "anything"? Is guvnor opened but no rule is shown? or not even that? Do you see any javascript error in your browser? any broken http request?

Comment: in this this case, "anything" means nothing...I put the URL directly in the browser and it shows a blank page. If I start making up more attributes on the URL it effectively tells me that there's a problem with the arguments. If I use only the two (and correct) arguments, it simply doesn't show anything...

Comment: Esteban, I was watching your video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXnG5o9wSZ4 and still can't get it to work...what you show there, the DSL guided editor is EXACTLY what I'm trying to achieve. I've copied your html source and changed the URL to my Guvnor's URL. Do you have any idea why it's not working? Has anything changed from the version you use in your tutorials to the 5.5.0 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct URL you have to invoke is:

`http://<address>:<port>/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/standaloneEditorServlet?assetsUUIDs=<uuid>&client=oryx`

This servlet will redirect your browser to StandaloneEditor.html.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Man...I can't believe this. The URL is VERY case sensitive. Thank you very much, I was pretty sure this error was something silly.

Comment: A trying page that shows some content on guvnor 5.5 is http://localhost:8080/guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/GuidedEditor.html